# Updating label takes too long (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm beginner swift developer. I'm stucked with this weather app.I'm downloading website data and then displaying in my label.

Unfortunately this whole process takes like 10 second to update my label.

This is probably not because of the network connection as the console is updated instantly.

Thanks for suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Without code, it's gonna be difficult to understand where could be your issue.

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: I bet you are doing something on the wrong thread. But you have to give us some code sample so we can help you...

Comment: You simply need to ensure that you update your UI on the main thread. Use a GCD call inside your block. See answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What happens is that code is probably run on a secondary thread. Any UI changes you make should be made on the main thread. So try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // update label
}
```

This should update your label instantly.

Comment: where to find this function? please

Answer (score 6):

Previously, we would choose the dispatch method (sync vs async) and then the queue we wanted to dispatch our task to. The updated GCD reverses this order - we first choose the queue and then apply a dispatch method.

> **Swift 3**:

Now in **Swift 3** the GCD library was updated like in the following way:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    // UI Updates
})
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late to answer but in  Swift 3 logic should be like this.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
// Background Thread Or Service call Or DB fetch etc
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Run UI Updates and other logic
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple issues.

FIRST: It has strong reference cycle

Fix it by putting this in closure.

```
 [weak weakSelf = self]
```

SECOND: Update UI in main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
 //Update UI
 weakSelf?.mReslut.text = ""
}
```