# asynchronous Swift function taking long time to update label

Tags: ios, swift

```
            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            // Get data as string
            if let object = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject] {
                let rows = object["rows"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                let elements = rows.first!["elements"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                let duration = elements.first!["duration"] as! [String:AnyObject]
                let durationText = duration["text"] as! String


                self.durationTime = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60)
                print("\(self.durationTime) is the duration time")

                let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
                self.newDate = self.datePicker.date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-self.durationTime)

                let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.newDate)
                print("\(strDate) is the time you should leave at @willcohen")

                self.finalTimeLabel.text = "\(strDate)"

                if self.finalTimeLabel.text != strDate {
                    self.finalTimeLabel.text = "Calculating time..."
                }

            }

        }).resume()
```

Hello, here I posted my code that I am using. As you can see, there is a completion handler on the top. I have cut a lot of the code in this section out because some of it was irrelevant. What I need to do here is change a label in my app to the variable `strDate`, however it seems to take a way long time to do. I know that this is asynchronous function, but strDate is printed immediately when I run my app on the line `print("\(strDate) is the time you should leave at")`, so I am not sure why it would delay so long (atleast 15-20 seconds) to update my label. So, my question is, how would I fix this problem to have the label updated immediately, just like `strDate` is printed immediately? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Less than a second. I think like .200 seconds to be exact

Comment: You're trying to update UI from a background thread, you should do it in the main thread instead.

Comment: I'm a bit unfamiliar with this. So, would I create a "dispatch_async" in the session that I just posted, or outside this? I tried to create a variable in the view did load and update it when I clicked a button, however it always comes up as nil.

Comment: @willcohen When you're updating `finalTimeLabel.text`, you're updating the user interface (UI). You cannot update the UI on a background thread. You wrap it with dispatch_async. See this answer--> http://stackoverflow.com/a/26013902/4475605